# How to write a byte array as bytes to a file

Tags: java, file

I want to write byte array to a file as bytes. 
e.g. `byt[] ="hello".getBytes();`
I want to write the byt to a file , such that I see the contents as bytes, not as "hello".
How can I do that?

Comment: Use a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html)

Comment: but it writes the contents as string not as bytes, I want the contents of file as some bytes , something like when you open a image file in text

Comment: It seems you don't understand what a "text file" is. A text file is simply a "binary file" in which the bytes fall into a known range, that a text editor knows to treat as "text".

Comment: `hello` is `0x68` `0x65` `0x6c` `0x6c` `0x6f` - but if you open a file with those bytes in it in a text editor, it will _render_ it as "hello".  If you opened the file in a hex editor, you would see the hex representation of those bytes.

Comment: This is the point I wanted to know..

Comment: 'I want to write the `byt` to a file , such that I see the contents as bytes, not as "hello"'. This requirement is meaningless. How you 'see' it depends entirely on what you use to look at it, and there is no essential difference between "hello" and the bytes that comprise it. Not a real question.

Comment: may be I couldnot put the question properly, Infact Greg was right about me .. and he understood the question .. thanks @Greg

Answer (score 3):

You can use [FileOutputStream#write(byte[] b)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write%28byte%5B%5D%29).

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(strFilePath);
String strContent = "hello";
fos.write(strContent.getBytes());
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following method

```
public static void writeByteCodeToFile(){
    String hello = "Hello";
    byte[] getByte = hello.getBytes();
    System.out.println(getByte); // output>>>[B@1df073d
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\Test.txt");
        try {
            fos.write(getByte);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Out put in the Test.txt contains the "Hello" while we can see console out put as [B@1df073d. Reason is text editor can render byte code as text.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of answers here, and one very important thing missing from all of them.

Do not use `String.getBytes()`.

**Always use `String.getBytes(Charset)`.**

Unknown (default) charset is the source of all (most of anyway) evil in file operations.

If you don't know which charset to use, just use UTF-8 and call `FileOutputStream.write(aString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));`

You can also define a charset to be used accross the whole appliaction, so that it is easily changable in the future.

```
class CharsetSettings {
  static final String fileOperationsCharset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
}
```